# How to Achieve this SQL statement with Crystal Reports?

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

Can someone please give me a lesson in how to achieve the following SQL statement in Crystal Reports?

```
select Debtor_Assessment_Facts.Assessment
from Debtor_Assessment_Facts
where Debtor_Assessment_Facts.Assessment_Facts_Key not in 
(
    select Debtor_Transaction_Facts.Assessment_Facts_Key
    from Debtor_Transaction_Facts
    inner join Debtor_Transaction_Types
    on Debtor_Transaction_Facts.Transaction_type_Key = Debtor_Transaction_Types.Transaction_Type_Key
    where Debtor_Transaction_Types.Transaction_Type_Code = 'RCPT' and Debtor_Transaction_Facts.Transaction_Date >= DATEADD(year,-6,GETDATE())
    group by Debtor_Transaction_Facts.Assessment_Facts_Key
)
and Debtor_Assessment_Facts.Balance <> 0
order by Debtor_Assessment_Facts.Assessment
```

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 0):

Open the crystal reports... make a database connection... do add command and paste your sql statement there and proceed with report design